# Intellij-idea Debugger - Coroutine tab : "An error occurred on fetching information"

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, coroutine

I'm trying to do some coroutine example represented on : https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide/example-basic-02.kt

and It's debugger not working properly.

[image: Intellij screenshot]

As you see, even code about coroutine like 'runBlocking' or 'launch' is not detected by intellisense,
I don't know what is my problem.

First my project is kotlin Console program, and

What I've done to import kotlinx.coroutine to my project are :

1. at Project Structure, Module downloaded org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-RC from Maven, when downloading checked Trasitive-something and Source, and added at library.
2. at Settings -> Build -> Kotlin compiler, changed language version and API version to 1.5, which is experimental version of Kotlin
3. at Project tool and build.gradle.kts, added
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-RC") at dependencies,
   kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.0" at plugins

Just run projects works well, but I can't use any context menu when using code about coroutine and as you know, it's really annoying me. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it seems to be fixed in 1.5.0. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-11620

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem today, I use the latest the Coroutine library version and my kotlin version is 1.6.21 which is not the latest.

I just update my kotlin version to the latest version 1.8.10.